# Should I put a comma around an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, commas

Should I put a comma around an adverb when it describes the circumstance that the sentence is describing?

1. "I, unfortunately, did not have an older brother to protect me."
2. "I unfortunately did not have an older brother to protect me."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an introductory adverbial element seems to modify the entire sentence and not just the verb or some single element in the rest of the sentence, put a comma after it.

> Fortunately, no one in the bridal party was in that car.
>
> Sadly, the old church was completely destroyed

In your case it is better to use the adverb in fronte of the whole sentence:

> Unfortunately, I didn't have an older brother to protect me.

Answer (score 1):

They are both acceptable but give different emphases. Your first variant emphasises the subject, and would be used to highlight contrast:

> The playground fight got rather nasty. Peter, as always, came out
>   unscathed. I, unfortunately, did not have an older brother to protect
>   me.

The other is the unmarked version:

> I was worried about being bullied as I started secondary school. I
>   unfortunately did not have an older brother to protect me.

The *pragmatic marker ... speaker stance* (traditionally, *sentence adverb*) may be fronted in either case, but the 'I' would need spoken emphasis to mirror the first example above. A comma would be usual though not really mandatory after introductory 'Unfortunately'.

Answer (score 0):

It's optional, but preferable, with supplements to set them off with punctuation.

Note that the adjunct "unfortunately" does not describe the circumstances. It doesn’t mediate the way in which the proposition relates to truth. In both your examples, the proposition that I did not have an older brother to protect me is presented as a fact, and the speaker adds an evaluation which amounts to saying "It is unfortunate for me that this is true".